# Reordering data into columns From and To

Tags: sql, oracle

This table Journey tracks a car while it is moving.

```
Journey   Chkpt1 Chkpt2
    51    AAA    BBB
    51    BBB    CCC
    51    DDD    CCC
    51    EEE    DDD
    51    EEE    FFF
```

It goes from the segment AAA-BBB to segment BBB-CCC, then to DDD-CCC, and so on.

But the columns Chkpt1 and Chkpt2 are not well ordered. 
I´d like to to generate a reordered table where one of the columns always means "From" and the other means "To" during a same journey. So we could easily see that this car is moving from AAA to BBB, from BBB to CCC, from CCC to DDD (and not from DDD to CCC).

The desired result would be:

```
Reordered Chkpt1 Chkpt2
    51    AAA    BBB
    51    BBB    CCC
    51    CCC    DDD    *
    51    DDD    EEE    *
    51    EEE    FFF
```

(The asterisks are only to mark the lines changed.)

On the next example, the car starts moving From Chkpt2 to Chkpt1.

Example 2:

```
Journey Chkpt1 Chkpt2
    52    NNN    MMM
    52    OOO    NNN
    52    PPP    OOO
    52    PPP    QQQ
    52    RRR    QQQ
```

All the lines below should be reordered the same way, from Chkpt2 to Chkpt1.

```
Reordered Chkpt1 Chkpt2
    52    NNN    MMM
    52    OOO    NNN
    52    PPP    OOO
    52    QQQ    PPP    *
    52    RRR    QQQ
```

How can this be done is SQL ?

Note: the result above is enough for me.
But, alternatively, the results could always be presented in two columns From and To.

```
Reordered2 From  To
    51    AAA    BBB
    51    BBB    CCC
    51    CCC    DDD    *
    51    DDD    EEE    *
    51    EEE    FFF
    52    NNN    MMM
    52    OOO    NNN
    52    PPP    OOO
    52    QQQ    PPP    *
    52    RRR    QQQ
```

Thanks in advance, 
Emerson

Comment: And what actually defines the order?

Comment: Here, too, you need to state that there will be no cycles on the journey. Then, in your first example, do you have a preference that the journey be from AAA to FFF, and not from FFF to AAA? Do you care? (In your earlier example you also had a time component that could be used to answer this question, but now you don't have it anymore.)

Comment: OK. Let´s suppose that we still have a TIME column and, in all examples shown, rows are presented in chronological order. There are no cycles in the journey. By this moment, I just need the simplest query to solve a question like this, not worrying about these details at first, though they can be important in many cases, but not in this case I´m dealing with. Which kind of SQL construction do I need to solve this kind of problem ? That is, sweeping a set of rows, and comparing each row with its previous row, reverting the values of Chkpt1 and Chkpt2 when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this - with a recursive query (therefore requiring Oracle 11.2 or higher). It shouldn't be too difficult to rewrite this with a hierarchical (`CONNECT BY`) query for older versions.

The query identifies the two endpoints of each journey, and it assumes the "origin" is the first one (in alphabetical order); so if the endpoints are identified as AAA and FFF, the query will choose AAA as the origin and FFF as the end of that journey. This can be changed easily in the `origins` factored subquery (CTE).

The output is ordered by journey and then by leg number (first, second etc.) The CHKPT columns are preserved, and the last two columns show the FROM and the TO endpoints of the respective leg.

```
with
  simulated_data (journey, chkpt1, chkpt2) as (
    select 51, 'AAA', 'BBB' from dual union all
    select 51, 'BBB', 'CCC' from dual union all
    select 51, 'DDD', 'CCC' from dual union all
    select 51, 'EEE', 'DDD' from dual union all
    select 51, 'EEE', 'FFF' from dual union all
    select 52, 'NNN', 'MMM' from dual union all
    select 52, 'OOO', 'NNN' from dual union all
    select 52, 'PPP', 'OOO' from dual union all
    select 52, 'PPP', 'QQQ' from dual union all
    select 52, 'RRR', 'QQQ' from dual
  ) -- select * from simulated_data; /*
, endpoints (journey, endpoint) as (
    select   journey, chkpt
    from     (
               select  journey, chkpt
               from    simulated_data
               unpivot (chkpt for col in (chkpt1, chkpt2))
             )
    group by journey, chkpt
    having   count(*) = 1
  )  -- select * from endpoints; /*
, origins (journey, orig) as (
    select   journey, min(endpoint)
    from     endpoints
    group by journey
  ) -- select * from origins; /*
, rec (journey, leg, chkpt1, chkpt2, leg_start, leg_end) as (
    select o.journey, 1, s.chkpt1, s.chkpt2, o.orig, 
           case o.orig when s.chkpt1 then chkpt2 else chkpt1 end
      from origins o join simulated_data s
                     on  o.journey = s.journey
                     and o.orig in (s.chkpt1, chkpt2)
    union all
    select r.journey, leg + 1, s.chkpt1, s.chkpt2, r.leg_end,
           case r.leg_end when s.chkpt1 then s.chkpt2 else s.chkpt1 end
      from rec r join simulated_data s
                 on   r.journey = s.journey
                 and  r.leg_end       in (s.chkpt1, s.chkpt2)
                 and  r.leg_start not in (s.chkpt1, s.chkpt2)
  )
select   journey, leg, chkpt1, chkpt2, leg_start, leg_end
from     rec
order by journey, leg
;
```

Output:

```
   JOURNEY        LEG  CHKPT1     CHKPT2     LEG_START  LEG_END   
---------- ----------  ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        51          1  AAA        BBB        AAA        BBB       
        51          2  BBB        CCC        BBB        CCC       
        51          3  DDD        CCC        CCC        DDD       
        51          4  EEE        DDD        DDD        EEE       
        51          5  EEE        FFF        EEE        FFF       
        52          1  NNN        MMM        MMM        NNN       
        52          2  OOO        NNN        NNN        OOO       
        52          3  PPP        OOO        OOO        PPP       
        52          4  PPP        QQQ        PPP        QQQ       
        52          5  RRR        QQQ        QQQ        RRR
```

Comment: @ mathguy: Well done. I´ve tested your solution adapting it to my real query and it worked nice ! I just had some work to discover how to replace your alphabetical ordering by my chronological order - that is, replacing "min (endpoint)" with the use of my Time column and some other subqueries. Many thanks !

Comment: And as I´m not much experienced, I thought there would be a quick way to do this task using some Oracle function. Now I see this question was much more complex than I imagined. Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a column which defines the order. I just "invented" one named `LEG`. Change it to your time stamp or whatever you have.

Then you can use `LEAD()` partitioned by the journey to check the values of the following row. If `chkpt1` is equal to any of the checkpoints of the following row, it has to be swapped for `chkpt2`. If `chkpt2` is equal to any of the two following, the order of the checkpoints already is right.

Put that in a `CASE ... END` to interchange the columns, if necessary.

If there is no following row however, `LEAD()` will return `NULL` and none of the equality checks will match. But it's possible that the columns in the last row of a journey also have to be interchanged. To handle that case add checks, that compare the checkpoints to the ones of the previous row using `LAG()`, with analog logic.

```
SELECT JOURNEY,
       CASE
         WHEN CHKPT1 IN (LEAD(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG),
                         LEAD(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT2
         WHEN CHKPT2 IN (LEAD(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG),
                         LEAD(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT1
         WHEN CHKPT1 IN (LAG(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG),
                         LAG(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT1
         WHEN CHKPT2 IN (LAG(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG),
                         LAG(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT2
       END CHKPT1,
       CASE
         WHEN CHKPT1 IN (LEAD(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG),
                         LEAD(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT1
         WHEN CHKPT2 IN (LEAD(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG),
                         LEAD(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                               ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT2
         WHEN CHKPT1 IN (LAG(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG),
                         LAG(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT2
         WHEN CHKPT2 IN (LAG(CHKPT1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG),
                         LAG(CHKPT2, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY JOURNEY
                                              ORDER BY LEG)) THEN
           CHKPT1
       END CHKPT2
       FROM JOURNEY;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed2161663ce6b3762e17a1b1e8fe5ee1)

Note:

It fails for cycles between only two checkpoints. But cycles spanning more than two checkpoints should work, I believe.

It might be possible to handle a cycle between only two checkpoints in general with an extra check but the direction cannot be deduced in that case, so any of them had to be taken randomly, not necessarily the right one.

It also fails for journeys, that span only two checkpoints (only one row in the table), as `LEAD()` and `LAG()` will both return `NULL`s. This might need an extra check. But as with the cycles over only two checkpoints, the order cannot be determined. The table's data might be right, it might be wrong, impossible to tell only with the given data at hand.

Comment: @ stickty bit: I´ve tested your solution ! Just a note: you called the result columns CHKPT1N and CHKPT1, and CHKPT1 is already a name from a previous column from Journey. I changed it and that worked fine ! It returns NULL when there´s only one row for the journey, as you told (and this may be useful for me as I need to find these cases). Your solution is closer to what I imagined how it would be, using a clear logic without using any special tools from Oracle SQL. Great work, also. Thanks !

Comment: @EmersonYassunaga: Sorry, I did test around and then copy and paste a little. Must have missed, that the aliases are still off from that. I corrected it to `CHKPT1` and `CHKPT2` in the answer, but of course you can rename them as you wish. I just didn't want to call them `FROM` or `TO` as those are reserved words (But they will work enclosed in double quotes.).